# List only those months that have entries

Tags: templating

I setup my archive using the Craft [demo](https://craftcms.com/support/entry-archive).  I have a page for each year.

I use [MixItUp](https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup/),(think Isotope) to allow a user to filter entries by month. There are simple hard coded buttons for each month.

How can I loop through the entries and create a button for only those months that have entries?

Update.  I have a loop that pulls all the entries for a given year.  I then use MixItUp (think Isotope) to filter the entries by month.

There is a button for each month that triggers MixItUp.  I want to make the creation of these buttons dynamic.  That is, I want to create a loop that generates a button for only those months that contain entries and create a class with the month's name that corresponds with the month in the class names of the entry cards.

For any given year, the loop would create 1-12 buttons.

```
{% for month that has > 0 entries %}

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg"   data-mixitup-control data-filter=".February">Feb</button>

{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
{% set date = (date()).modify('first day of january 00:00:00') %}
{% for month in 1..12 %}
    {% set endOfMonth = clone(date).modify('last day of this month') %}
        {% set exists= craft.entries
            .postDate(['and', '>=' ~ date.format('-.m-d H:i:s'), '<=' ~ endOfMonth.format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ])
            .exists()
        %}

    {% do date.modify('first day of next month') %}
{% endfor %}
```

loop all months and check if there are entries in this month or not

Comment: I am not getting it.  I updated my question.  I can't seem to get this to pull only those months with entries.

Comment: What doesn't work... "I don't get it" is not really helpful. My code loops all months and tries to fetch the corresponding entries where `postDate` is within this month, if entries with such a condition exists -> if the `exists` variable is true you can display the button, if `exists` is not true the month doesn't have entries